# Error while doing internationalization for Grails application

Tags: grails, internationalization

I'm doing internationalization for my Grails application, this what in my domain:

```
category (nullable:false, inList:Holders.config.categories)
```

and this in the `Config.groovy` file :

```
categories=['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3']
```

and this what in the `messages.properties` file:

```
 ads.category.cat1=category 1
 ads.category.cat2=category 2
 ads.category.cat3=category 3
```

what in the **show** view:

```
<g:if test="${adsInstance?.category}">
            <li class="fieldcontain">
                <span id="category-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="ads.category.label" default="Category" /></span>

                    <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="category-label"><g:fieldValue   bean="${adsInstance}" field="category"/></span>

            </li>
            </g:if>
```

All views showing the right words, except `show` showing `cat1` (this is what found in the config file) and this what was saved in the DB too as it supposes to show and save what in the `messages.properties` file `category 1`. How can I fix that?

Comment: Please provide the code of view for show function.

Comment: @MamyKryzysKryzysKryzys i edited the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<g:message code="ads.category.${adsInstance.category}" />
```

instead of

```
<g:fieldValue bean="${adsInstance}" field="category"/>
```

Comment: Great , worked in the view, but what about the DB part?

Comment: If you save it as *category 1* instead of *cat1* it won't work (I'm talking about translating a view) anymore. 
Moreover what is the point of using translation in view if you already saved translated field to db?

Why don;t you use beforeValidate() when obtaining field from db?

Comment: do you mean using `beforeValidate()` instead of the translation while getting a field from DB ?

Comment: yes, it's one possibility. imho storing translated fields in db is pointless.

Comment: or i may change `categories=['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3']` to be something meaningful , so if what to do any queries from the DB i can. what do you think?

Comment: If I were you I'd not put these categories in config but in another domain class, to have more control on them, too.

Comment: if i will put them in a domain how i'll do the internationalization?